# Difference in syntax in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have started learning typescript and came across defining the type of an argument in a different way than usual.

```
function postThread({userId}:{userId:string}) {
  // code to be executed
}
```

instead of this

```
function postThread({userId}:string) {
  // code to be executed
}
```

why can't we directly assign the type to it?

Comment: `{userId, someNumber}: string` — What now…?

Comment: `{userId}` is destructuring the parameter. The parameter type is a string. So, how exactly do you get the property `userId` from a primitive string which doesn't have that property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down the differences:

```
function postThread({userId}:{userId:string}) {
  // code to be executed
}
```

In this case, you're using object destructuring in the function parameter. The function postThread expects a single argument, which should be an object with a property named `userId` of type string.

```
function postThread({userId}:string) {
  // code to be executed
}
```

In this version, you're directly specifying that the function expects a single argument of type string. This is not using object destructuring, but rather just declaring the expected type of the parameter. However, this seems to be incorrect, as you're trying to **destructure an object, but the provided type is just string.**

Answer (score 1):

In your first example you explicitly add a type to your object parameter which is destructured immediately .

```
function postThread({userId}:{userId:string}) { // destructuring
  // code to be executed
}
```

---

Your second example produces a compiler error. Again, you destructure a property `userId` of an object parameter which has a explicit type of `string`. However, a primitive `string` does not have a property `userId`.

```
function postThread({userId}: string) {
  //                 ~~~~~~
  // Property 'userId' does not exist on type 'String'.
}
```

Unless you actually defined `userId` on the `String` interface:

```
interface String {
  userId: string;
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABzgZygFQBYCcCmAhgCYAUA3iGvrgJLEC%20AXIhrjGAOYCUi5AsAChEiAPSiRkqdMkA-eQqEjxiAAq44yGlACeiAORUa9fYmJx8aRGDhRE%20AB4wMiBIl1aDAZSjsu%20gDohBiEhIA)

Answer (score 1):

```
function postThread({ userId }: { userId: string }) {
  console.log(userId) // logs a string
}

postThread({ userId: 'abc123' })
```

This declares an object type `{ userId: string }`, and destructures the `userId` property from the parameter with that object type.

Note how when you call the function, you pass it an object with a `userId` property.

This is basically equivalent to:

```
function postThread(props: { userId: string }) {
  const userId = props.userId
  console.log(userId) // logs a string
}

postThread({ userId: 'abc123' })
```

---

```
function postThread({ userId }: string) {
  // will not compile
}
```

This is not valid. `{ userId }: string` attempts to access the `userId` property of a string, which won't work. This will raise a type error.

---

A common alternative, and what your second snippet probably meant to show, is this:

```
function postThread(userId: string) {
  console.log(userId) // logs a string
}

postThread('abc123')
```

In this example, the function accepts a simple `string` parameter.

Note how when you call the function, you pass it a string, and not an object.